# Unable to init PLPlot library in wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets, c++14, eclipse-cdt, mingw32

I am working on a project which aims at plotting a graph. To do so, I install PLPlot and I follow instruction provided [wxWidgets driver](https://sourceforge.net/p/plplot/wiki/Configuration_of_wxWidgets_driver/) and [Pplot for MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/p/plplot/wiki/Configure_PLplot_for_MinGW_CLI/). The build commmand line is defined as follows:

`mkdir buildmingw
cd buildmingw
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_TEST=ON -DwxWidgets_LIB_DIR=%WxLIBS%\lib\gcc_lib -DwxWidgets_CONFIGURATION=mswud -DwxWidgets_MONOLITHIC=ON -DwxWidgets_USE_UNICODE=ON -DwxWidgets_USE_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install ..
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install`

Then I create a notebookPage that handle the Pplot graphs using 'wxPLplotstream' provided in Bindings/wxWidgets. When I run my application, It loops during the Plplot initialization and crashes . How can I solve my problem? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: can you show us some actual code and not the instruction on how to build the library?

Comment: Please find 'wxPLplotstream' code (.h et cpp).

Comment: Sorry, how can be add code? In fact I try to add it in my message but I get error message "too long message". Thanks you in advance

Comment: do not drop the whole file. Put only the stuff relevant to the issue. That should be ~15-20 lines of C++ code.